# If you drop a bouncy ball on a level surface doesn’t it never stop bouncing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I realized this because of the Infinite Divisibility Theory. Which states that you can infinitely keep splitting something in half. Furthermore it would keep bouncing because there would always be a space between the surface and the ball’s surface. Also the only reason why we can’t see it bouncing is because it is an extremely small distance between the surface of the ball and the surface it’s bouncing on.

Comment: If the time of the first **round-trip** bounce is $T$, then the total time will be $$T \times \left[1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots \right] = 2T.$$  See also [Zeno's Paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes).

Comment: Is space infinitely divisible? What happens when the distances involved are less than the width of a proton? etc.

Comment: What the comments above imply is that your physical model for the bouncy ball is no longer accurate in certain limits

Comment: What are those limits

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question you have to distinguish between the physical system and the mathematical model.

If the bounces are from inelastic collisions between the ball and the immovable surface then the bounce height never decreases and the motion is periodic. In the real world that's impossible.

For elastic collisions you need to take into account the energy lost to heat when the ball and the surface momentarily contract and rebound at the bounce. Then the bounces are smaller and smaller as time goes by. I can imagine mathematical models where the magnitude decays to 0 in finite time  or in infinite time (I don't know enough physics to decide which is realistic. I suspect the former).

But any good model of the macroscopic behavior will fail at small times and distances. Then quantum mechanics takes over.

Comment: But wouldn’t’t there always have a space no matter how small be made

Comment: Your comment makes no sense at small distances. For an analogy, think of a fuzzy tennis ball bouncing on a shag carpet. The contact is not instantaneous. Near the time of contact you can't really tell where the ball ends and the carpet begins. At really  small distances the world is weird. Newton's mathematics no longer predicts the results of experiments in physics. The mathematics of quantum mechanics does much better. But it's not the last word. There's still physics we can't model correctly. See https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length

Answer (score 2):

Mathematics is a tool for modelling real world phenomena; real world phenomena is *not* mathematics. Math will only be as useful insofar as the asssumptions underlying the math are dually satisfied by the real world system. For instance, you reasoning suggests that space can be infinitely divided, but there is a limit to the smallest unit of space known as the [Planck distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#Planck_length), according to the best currently accepted theory in physics.

Comment: I don’t know how there is not something smaller than planck distance

Comment: yes, it is difficult to imagine a very small unit of indivisible space, but the standard model of physics suggests this indeed exists. Part of the problem is that you are using your mathematical intuition to deduce something about the real world. While this has the potential to lead great insights, it can also be dangerous if you are not aware the of limits of this kind of reasoning. Various branches of mathematics are predicated on fundamental sets of assumptions (axioms) we simply assume to be true. The physics of the universe also appears to obey a fundamental set of laws...

Comment: but the fundamental laws of the universe and the axioms of our mathematics are not necessarily one and the same. The latter was determined by us. The former was determined independently of us.

Answer (score 0):

The ball couldn't keep jumping. As @EthanBolker said, each bounce becomes smaller. But space is actually not continuous, contrary to what most people think. It is actually discrete, and the smallest possible length where physics makes sense is known as the Planck length. If we let the ball bounce until its last bounce was of height $l\le a\le2l$, where $l$ is the Planck length, then the ball will have to stop bouncing.